# Saving LTspice colors & drafting settings on CrossOver (Wine)

Tags: ltspice, osx

I run LTspice XVII on mac OSX using CrossOver (Wine), as I prefer having access to the toolbar and menus in the Windows app that are absent within the native mac app.

It works well, except that changes to the drafting settings and colors in the `Tools > Control Panel` and `Tools > Color Preferences` menus do not persist between program invocations.

It's a nuisance to reconfigure options each time the program launches. Any idea why this is happening or where LTspice normally stores the settings on Windows?

Example style that differs from the default:

[image: Example styling]

Comment: Figuring out problems with Wine might be better asked on SuperUser or the Apple StackExchange.  To answer the easy question, the LTspice settings are typically stored in the following file on a Windows machine: `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\LTspiceXVII.ini`

Comment: @SteKulov Interesting, `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\LTspiceXVII.ini` doesn't exist in the Wine virtual C drive. I wonder what will happen when I create it.

Comment: @SteKulov After adding an empty `.ini` in `C:\users\crossover\AppData` (not in `Roaming`) and changing permissions to allow Read/Write, LTspice appears to persist the settings. Thanks.

Comment: This sounds like a problem for CrossOver, since Wine has none such. Or maybe it's the OSX environment?